# window.A_TCALSIDX.length is null or not an object Error

Tags: javascript

In ASP.NET 2.0 when i scroll down the aspx page I get folowing script error -

> window.A_TCALSIDX.length is null or not an object Error

Comment: i dont have any element in my code such as window.A_TCALSIDX.length 
Please help

Answer (score 0):

You probably installed the tigra calender, check the javascript code